# On android (glsurfaceview) textures are white after MainActivity.finish() and MainActivity.onDestroy()

Tags: android, screen, glsurfaceview, ondestroy

Working on an app that uses a MainActivity->RelativeLayout->GLSurfaceView.

When exiting the app (OK, per contractor requirement) via Activity.finish(), on next launch it will start in its initial state (OK, per contractor requirement) but all textures will be white.

Closing the application via System.exit(0) fixes this, so it's pretty obvious that some form of
OpenGL resource is not being freed.
The textures should all be freed, since there's a manager for them, and none seem to leak.

I'm looking to replace System.exit(0) with something that flushes all OpenGL resources (if possible) ?
Is there something like a context destroyer exposed on Android ?

Comment: It's an unusual situation. You might make a mistake. But I don't cannot guess what is your mistake. Give me a clue to solve your problem.